# How can I detect if a grouped result of the mySQL database has any related value?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-by

```
animal    food
cat
cat       mouse
cat       
dog
dog
bird      carrot
bird      herb
bird
```

I have some animals in my mysql database. My problem is that I need to know, if any animal of a animal-group got food.

```
 $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM list GROUP BY animal');
 while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row["food"]){
       echo "Some ".$row["animal"]." got food.<br>";
    } else {
       echo "No " .$row["animal"]. " got food.<br>";
  }
}
```

My result is:

```
No cat got food.
No dog got food.
No bird got food.
```

But I expect:

```
Some cat got food.
No dog got food.
Some bird got food.
```

Comment: `if (($row["animal"] == "cat" || $row["animal"] == "bird") && $row["food"] == "yes")` something like that could work. Maybe a CASE would be better though with a ternary.

Comment: and now you went and edited. That ^ was as per your original post. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44391985/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- 
 
Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It is not "YES" instead it is the name of the food in my database. I edited the quesion

Comment: see the answers then below, looks promising but those may have been based on your original post

Comment: I've been looking at the question etc. for a bit, `if (($row["animal"] == "cat" || $row["animal"] == "bird") && !empty($row["food"]))` could work; try that, being a php method. You could also add to the first conditionals for extra column(s).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the idea, but I have much more animals in my list, so this is not working for me

Comment: `if ($row["animal"] && !empty($row["food"]) )` which I had thought of just now *lol* Besides that, I don't know.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tested this also but I get the same result I got `No cat got food.
No dog got food.
No bird got food.`

Comment: Gosh darn it *lol!* Did you try swapping the `&&` for an `||` ?

Comment: Now the result is `Some cat got food. Some dog got food. Some bird got food.`

Comment: Well... I was kind of close *lol!* - Glad to see you got your solution. Funny enough, I was going to ask you earlier if you had tried Rahul's answer but failed to do so. *Cheers!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
$pdo = $db->query("SELECT animal,sum(if(food<>'',1,0)) AS count_of_food FROM 
list GROUP BY animal");
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row["count_of_food"]>0){
       echo "Some ".$row["animal"]." got food.<br>";
    } else {
       echo "No " .$row["animal"]. " got food.<br>";
    }
}
```

edit 1

by checking `food<>'',1,0`. Let's take the example of `cat`. for first row it will return 0 because the food column is blank hence 0, for second it will return 1 and third row it will return 0.

[image: Table output]

And your second question, What if you want check for all animal had food. Just take the count of all animal.

```
$pdo = $db->query("SELECT animal,sum(if(food<>'',1,0)) AS count_of_food,count(1) AS total_cnt FROM list GROUP BY animal");
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row["count_of_food"]==$row["total_cnt"]){
       echo "All ".$row["animal"]." got food.<br>";
    }else if($row["count_of_food"]>0){
       echo "Some ".$row["animal"]." got food.<br>";
    } else {
       echo "No " .$row["animal"]. " got food.<br>";
    }
}
```

Output of second query will be

[image: Output of second query will be]

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you did here: `food<>'',1,0`

Comment: Agreed ^ Explaining the solution would be beneficial for all and for future visitors.

Comment: Is for your solution the option `"All " .$row["animal"]. " got food` possible?

Comment: @Jarla Gotta wonder about *"After sales service'* huh? *lol* The guy should be updating the answer and responding to your comment. If he doesn't let me know. It shouldn't be up to me to answer your comment about the "All" thing, I hope you understand ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I know how to do it. It is `if($row["count_of_food"]>1){`

Comment: @Rahul Singh Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could count all the records for the animal and compare that to a count of records where `food='yes'` and make you determination based on that:

```
SELECT
    animal,
    sum(CASE WHEN food IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) as percentage_fed
FROM list
GROUP BY animal
```

The just test that: If percentage_fed < 1 then "Some" else if percentage_fed = 0 then "none" else "all"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. It is not "YES" instead it is the name of the food in my database. I updated my question

Comment: No worries. I swapped the logic around for that.

Comment: I am still testing your answer, but cannot get it run. I will search for the mistake

Comment: You could do this in two fields if the math and field types are causing a problem (it may be only outputting integers from the math problem depending on your field types and how much pixie dust has been spread in your database. Something like `SELECT animal, um(CASE WHEN food IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as food_eaten, COUNT(*) as food_total ...` then do the comparison in PHP for `food_eaten` to `total_food`. Similar to other answers here, but this allows you to test for `none`, `some`, or `all` (or even state the percentage eaten if that works for this data).

Comment: Ok, I will test it now

Comment: The problem is this line `percentage_fed = 0`. I get a blank page. percentage_fed <1` is giving me the result "Some". But for all animals, no matter if they eaten food or not

Comment: I tested `SELECT animal, um(CASE WHEN food IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as food_eaten, COUNT(*) as food_total ...` but still have an error

Comment: should be `sum(`. Is that the error you're getting that there is a problem near the word `um`?

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of an aggregate function, e.g.

```
 SELECT t.animal
      , MAX(t.food) AS food
   FROM list t 
  GROUP BY t.animal
  ORDER BY t.animal
```

or conditional aggregation, e.g.:

```
 SELECT t.animal
      , COUNT(IF(t.food>'',1,NULL)) AS food
   FROM list t
  GROUP BY t.animal
  ORDER BY t.animal
```

Comment: I tested your answer. The first code is giving me the result `No cat got food.
No dog got food.
No bird got food.` The second code is giving me no results. I am still checking out why this is happening